# Firestore slow queries are causing the entire logic to crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently designing a todo app with react and firebase without any node js server code. Everything was fine when inserting data and authenticating, but when I tried to query all the tasks where `uid` equals a certain value(that means all the tasks that belongs to a particular user), somehow the query gets skipped and returns null. But then, after a second or so, the array got retrieved and printed out.

The code:

```js
function retrieveTasksOfUser(uid) {
    // get all tasks where the uid equals the given value
    return db.collection("tasks").where("uid", "==", uid).get();
}

function retrieveTasks() {
    let res = [];
    retrieveTasksOfUser(currentUser["uid"])
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // include the doc id in each returned object
            let buffer = doc.data();
            buffer["id"] = doc.id;
            res.push(buffer);
        });
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error retrieving tasks: ", err);
        return res;
    });
}
let tasks = retrieveTasks();
console.log({ tasks });
```

EDIT:
Inspired by Frank's answer, I modified my code and got:

```
    async function retrieveTasks() {
        let res = [];
        const snapshot = await retrieveTasksOfUser(currentUser["uid"]);
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let buffer = doc.data();
            buffer["id"] = doc.id;
            res.push(buffer);
        });
        return res;
    }

    let tasks = [];
    let promise = retrieveTasks();
    promise.then((res) => {
        console.log("Tasks are");
        tasks = res;
        console.log(res);
    });
    console.log(tasks);
```

But the result turns out to be an empty array
[image]

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: In that last bit you added, you are calling `console.log(tasks)` right after setting it to `[]`. Anything that you've attached to the promise isn't executed until later. I recommend watching this video and learning [how the event loop works](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0).

Comment: the key here is to bring that `res` variable out somehow so that I can render my components that must use this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the top-level code in `retrieveTasks`, so that means that `tasks` will always be `undefined`.

The simplest fix is to return the result of the query, which then means that your `return res` will be bubbled up:

```
return retrieveTasksOfUser(currentUser["uid"])
    ...
```

But this means you're returning a promise, as the data is loaded asynchronously. So in the calling code, you have to wait for that promise to resolve with then:

```
retrieveTasks().then((tasks) => {
    console.log({ tasks });
})
```

---

You can make all of this a lot more readable (although it'll function exactly the same) by using the [`async` and `await` keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

With those, the code would become:

```
async function retrieveTasks() {
    let res = [];
    const snapshot = await retrieveTasksOfUser(currentUser["uid"]);
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let buffer = doc.data();
        buffer["id"] = doc.id;
        res.push(buffer);
    });
    return res;
}
let tasks = await retrieveTasks();
console.log({ tasks });
```

Or with a bit more modern JavaScript magic, we can make it even shorter:

```
async function retrieveTasks() {
    const snapshot = await retrieveTasksOfUser(currentUser["uid"]);
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => { ...doc.data, id: doc.id });
}
let tasks = await retrieveTasks();
console.log({ tasks });
```